# Variable not holding data from MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code

```
# connect to sql server
$sql = new PDO('mysql:dbname=random;host=localhost', 'root', '');

# perform the query
$query = 'SET @uid := (SELECT Channel_Location FROM channels WHERE Used = 0 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1);'.PHP_EOL
    .'UPDATE channels SET Used = 1 WHERE Channel_Location = @uid;'.PHP_EOL
    .'SELECT * FROM channels WHERE Channel_Location = @uid';

$result = $sql->query($query);
$row = $result->fetch();
$id = $row['Channel_Location'];
var_dump($row);
```

Now the query works its tested returns what i need it to but when i `var_dump($row)` i get Boolean false and when i `var_dump($id)` i get null  as the errors, now the database has plenty of entries it can select from but nothing passes through to PHP yet if i run the query in my client i get a return value.

can anyone guide me to a possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can't run multiple queries in one using PDO, try running one query at time and check to see what happens

Comment: In fact, [you can](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#multiquery). But I agree with the suggestion.